# Use Google API Key to Translate Entire Website - Third party cookie will be blocked

Tags: google-translate, madcap, community-translations

We currently use MadCap Flare (CSS and HTML) to generate our online help (hosted in AWS). We were using the Google Translate widget to fulfill several contractual agreements, however, it is no longer supported. I am looking for a way to add a button on my site that allows the user to select a language and have the content sitewide dynamically change.

I'm no programmer, but my company has a Google API key, so I have  used the code here in the CSS on my Masterpages: (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-google-translate-button-on-your-webpage). This works, but throws 25 "Third-party will be blocked" errors in the console. Is there a way to resolve this? I haven't found anything helpful on the Cloud Translation site, so thought I would try here, as there are surely others in my position.

[Screenshot of Cookie errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZLnD.png)